# Get Next Value from Current ID by using Query

Tags: mysql

I have selected some values from Table.

MY code

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, CAST( NULL AS CHAR ) , CAST( NULL AS CHAR )
FROM ATTRIBUTEUSE AU
JOIN ATTRIBUTE A ON AU.ATTRIBUTE_ID = A.ID
WHERE AU.ATTRIBUTESET_ID = 'eeeaed05-dbf6-4300-8ebb-8c705b927d55 '
AND A.ID > 'd1abc226-fadd-495f-8b65-0b550fa046ce'
ORDER BY AU.LINENO
LIMIT 1 ;

Name      ID
Soft      d1abc226-fadd-495f-8b65-0b550fa046ce
Hot       60009233-9668-45da-a7cd-57ad9d15a378
Herbal    654b20ba-c0a9-476b-b5d1-052bf190fb1e
Cocktail  675745f0-9266-402e-8f58-763bdf9a4bed
```

I have some ID and i need the next value of Current Id

(i.e) If i have ID = '60009233-9668-45da-a7cd-57ad9d15a378' then i need the next value that is ID = '654b20ba-c0a9-476b-b5d1-052bf190fb1e';

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres? You have added both tags

Comment: I can help you by giving this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058328/next-and-previous-mysql-row-based-on-name  I hope this will help you to understand

Comment: Do You have any auto incremented id?

Answer (score 0):

Try with LIMIT

```
Select ID,Name 
FROM C_NAME where id>input_id 
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes, I do it. check it

Comment: Its retrun 0 Rows , see my query in Updated post

Comment: @Sadikhasan What will happen if it is last value . Eg. `Select ID,Name From C_NAME where id > 4 ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1`

Comment: Return empty if id not greater then input id

Comment: @Sadikhasan That could be one of the problem to the User he is getting 0 Rows . Check user edited the code its not INT to check the condition   > it may now var char